# Unable to run custom hyperledger network local network running on ubuntu

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger fabric and I was trying to test hyperledger fabric sample "fabcar" network with hyperledger fabric.I have done some edit in "org1" to "dfarmadmin".I have edited fabric  configtx.yaml,crypto-config.yaml and docker-compose.yml. I'm getting the following error when trying to run ./startFabric.sh into project.

Error response from daemon: Container 5266e6d8297848fb888d15b60aba3d66e5d31b7fc42a37616874c540eedb514e is not running. please see below screenshot for reference and link of files which I have edited "https://github.com/abhisamant7/tuna-Fish/tree/master/dfarm-network"

Please see the below docker logs of three docker container which was exited.

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to screenshot, peer, orderer and ca processes has been crashed. can you please post logs of these processes. I hope there is some issue with configuration, due to which it got crashed.

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have added the configuration file in link

Comment: Hi, I want to see logs, please collect logs using following commands:-

docker logs <container name>

e.g. docker logs peer0.dfarmadmin.com

Comment: @Abhirock I've checked your repo and your msp in crypto-config directory is not generated correctly

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have attached the screen shot of error and docker containers. please let me know anything need to rectify the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have done the very basic mistake of naming the domains of both peer and orderer org the same. Check your crypto-config.yaml file and change the domain name here:

```
OrdererOrgs:

  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: dfarmadmin.com
PeerOrgs:

  - Name: Dfarmadmin
    Domain: **CHANGE THIS**
```

Also change this in your configtx file:

```
 # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
 MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
```

to this:

```
 # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
 MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/msp
```

Comment: OrdererOrgs:

  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: orderer.dfarmadmin.com  // I have change like that 
PeerOrgs:

  - Name: Dfarmadmin
    Domain: dfarmadmin.com

Comment: You can change like this: OrdererOrgs: - Name: Orderer Domain: dfarmadmin.com PeerOrgs: - Name: Dfarmadmin Domain: peer.dfarmadmin.com

Comment: Hi, So have to change the "crypto-config" folder structure also?

Comment: You have to name the domain according to the domain that you have specified in the crypto-config. So just delete the previous crypto-config directory and stop the network then regenerate the artifacts and start the network with the updated crypto-config and configtx file.

Comment: Thanks however its still give issue. can I share screen shot of error. and docker logs of container which have issue?

Comment: Yes, share the screenshot if it still doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

1. Your volumes in the compose file are pointing towards the msp's
   present in the crypto-config folder,but the crypto-config folder
   doesnt have all msps files,some files are missing(like ca-key-file).
2. Your compose file is pointing towards a file which isnt present.So i
   would say delete and recreate the msps and point it correctly in the
   compose file

Eg.

```
services:
  ca.dfarmadmin.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.dfarmadmin.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/4239aa0dcd76daeeb8ba0cda701851d14504d31aad1b2ddddbac6a57365e497c_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.dfarmadmin.com
    networks:
- dfarm
```

As you can see your `- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE` is pointing to a file which is not present.

Comment: sorry It's a silly mistake as I didn't see that - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE is hard coded as "4239aa0dcd76daeeb8ba0cda701851d14504d31aad1b2ddddbac6a57365e497c_sk"